# Spring integration : trace propagation via micrometer on different channels?

Tags: spring-integration, spring-micrometer, spring-integration-sftp, micrometer-tracing

I am facing problems with setting up the trace propagation correctly, if there is a `QueueChannel` with a poller in between :(

Flow is initiated by HTTP call, that triggers `MessagingGateway` from spring integration:

```java
@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
class FooController {

    private final InitiateSftpImportGateway gateway;

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
    @PostMapping("/bar")
    void runImportAt(@RequestParam String path) {
        gateway.runImportAt(path);
    }

    @MessagingGateway(defaultRequestChannel = "sftpListingChannel", errorChannel = "errorChannel")
    interface InitiateSftpImportGateway {
        @Gateway
        void runImportAt(String path);
    }
}
```

channels are defined as follows:

```java
    @Bean
    MessageChannel sftpListingChannel(final ObservationRegistry observationRegistry) {
        final var directChannel = new DirectChannel();
        directChannel.registerObservationRegistry(observationRegistry);
        return directChannel;
    }

    @Bean
    MessageChannel sftpFetchingChannel(final ObservationRegistry observationRegistry) {
        final var queueChannel = new QueueChannel();
        queueChannel.registerObservationRegistry(observationRegistry);
        return queueChannel;
    }
```

and a snippet from actual flow - based on trigger, `sftpListingChannel` pulls files on SFTP:

```java
    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "sftpListingChannel", outputChannel = "fileSplittingChannel")
    MessageHandler listFiles(final CachingSessionFactory<SftpClient.DirEntry> cachingSessionFactory) {
        final var outboundGateway = new SftpOutboundGateway(
            cachingSessionFactory,
            AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.Command.LS.getCommand(),
            "payload"
        );
        outboundGateway.setOption(AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.Option.RECURSIVE);
        return outboundGateway;
    }
```

and splits them:

```java
    @Splitter(inputChannel = "fileSplittingChannel", outputChannel = "sftpFetchingChannel")
    List<FileInfo<SftpClient.DirEntry>> splitByFile(@Payload final List<FileInfo<SftpClient.DirEntry>> fileInfo) {
        return fileInfo;
    }
```

for each file - we download it:

```java
    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(
        inputChannel = "sftpFetchingChannel",
        outputChannel = "...",
        poller = @Poller(value = "transactionalPoller")
    )
    MessageHandler fetchFiles(CachingSessionFactory<SftpClient.DirEntry> cachingSessionFactory) {
        final var outboundGateway = new SftpOutboundGateway(
            cachingSessionFactory,
            AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.Command.GET.getCommand(),
            Constants.Expressions.FILE_LOCATION_FROM_HEADER
        );
        outboundGateway.setOption(
            AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.Option.STREAM,
            AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.Option.PRESERVE_TIMESTAMP
        );
        return outboundGateway;
    }
```

which uses a custom-poller, to inject transaction advice:

```java
    @Bean
    PollerMetadata transactionalPoller(final TransactionManager transactionManager) {
        final var pollerMetadata = new PollerMetadata();

        pollerMetadata.setAdviceChain(
            List.of(new TransactionInterceptorBuilder().transactionManager(transactionManager).build())
        );

        return pollerMetadata;
    }
```

The poller (?) terminates initial trace and initialises a new one - this is troublesome as I would like to track the overall flow and just relay on span IDs to deep-dive into particular file-sub-process.

My biggest concern is the `errorChannel` - if some sub-operation after split throws an error, it is handled on `errorChannel` but with a new trace ID :(

Kindly advise if/how should I adjust my config to make trace propagation smoother.

---

Disclaimer:

- it may look strange that instead of plain `get` there is `ls` first (or even an adapter) - code above is just a small sub-set of bigger flow
- why queue channel with a poller? basically - I wanted to have a "for-each-loop" with independent, transacted error handling, so that one file does not break the flow and it may still continue

---

For the record:

- spring-integration:6.1.4
- spring-boot: 3.1.5
- micrometer-tracing (with brave bridge): 1.1.6

---

#### update @ 02JAN (*based on comment from @artem*)

Adjusted config for queue channel registration:

```java
    @Bean
    MessageChannel sftpFetchingChannel() {
        return new QueueChannel();
    }
```

(btw - do I still need to call `registerObservationRegistry` here?)

and added

```java
    @Bean
    @GlobalChannelInterceptor
    ObservationPropagationChannelInterceptor observationPropagationChannelInterceptor(
        final ObservationRegistry observationRegistry
    ) {
        return new ObservationPropagationChannelInterceptor(observationRegistry);
    }
```

this solved the trace propagation "end-to-end", ...without error channel :( there, I still get new trace being initiated or none at all (depends on further config); I tried my own registration:

```java
    @Bean
    MessageChannel errorChannel(final ObservationPropagationChannelInterceptor observationPropagationChannelInterceptor) {
        final var directChannel = new DirectChannel();
        directChannel.addInterceptor(observationPropagationChannelInterceptor);  //ignored whatsoever and no trace
        //directChannel.registerObservationRegistry(observationRegistry); creates new trace
        return directChannel;
    }
```

do I miss something in regards to `errorChannel` definition?

btw, consumer of error channel is:

```java
    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "errorChannel")
    MessageHandler handleIntegrationErrors() {
        return message -> {
            // do some logging
            }
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really are missing an [Observation Propagation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/metrics.html#observation-propagation). The `QueueChannel` is consumed on the other thread and there is no knowledge about the trace in the producer thread. So, you need to configure the mentioned `ObservationPropagationChannelInterceptor` to propagate the trace from producer to consumer via message stored in that channel.

Comment: thx <3; I did try mentioned documentation before - and no luck; I tried again with different ways of wiring it up and partial success (description updated) - so 'GlobalChannelInterceptor' works for queueChannel but not for (my) errorChannel :(

Comment: Well, when error happens, we close the current observation and only after that such an error is sent to the `errorChannel`. So, the behavior is really expected. You cannot infer to the fact that an observation is in error state. Such an error handling is out of trace scope.

Comment: thx again; this is what I was afraid of, debugging `MessagePublishingErrorHandler` - but still hopping I miss something; very last question if I may - do I still need to call `registerObservationRegistry` on a channel, if I am registering global `ObservationPropagationChannelInterceptor`?

Comment: If you want to include that channel into a trace, then observation has to be added to that channel. The `ObservationPropagationChannelInterceptor` does not do that. It is slightly different functionality.